# How can I decouple my models when I'm using Room

Tags: android, android-room, clean-architecture

To preface this, I'm fairly new to Android development and I'm currently trying to learn by building an app while following Clean Architecture.

I currently have a model called "Card" and the Room library for storing all "Card" data. However, the only way I've found to implement the Room library in my app is by designating "Card" model as my entity which resides in the domain layer of my app. From my understanding, this violates the decoupling of layers as the domain layer is supposed to be independent of the framework.

```
@Entity
public class CardImpl implements Card {
  @PrimaryKey
  @NonNull
  public String cardID;

  @ColumnInfo(name = "card_name")
  public String name;

  @ColumnInfo(name = "card_class")
  public String cardClass;

  @ColumnInfo(name = "card_text")
  public String text;

  @ColumnInfo(name = "card_cost")
  public int cost;
```

I've tried subclassing the model as a decorator but couldn't get the annotations to work on the subclass. Is there a better approach for this and is this something I should be concerned about?

Also I'm not sure how much information you need to answer my question, but please let me know if you need more! Thanks!

Comment: I don't know room library but what should always work is having two independent objects (one from domain and one defined in persistence layer), a repository and manually mapping between both objects.

Comment: Oh ok, I tried creating a decorator for the original Entity class but I think the approach with mapping two independent classes addresses the issue I had with annotations. Is this is common solution to this kind of problem?

Comment: It is a common approach if u want to keep ur domain model independent from persistence and ur persistence fw requires certain kind of annotations. Some frameworks support convention over configuration or configuration without annotations. In such cases obviously no duplicate classes are required. Don't know whether either approach is possible with room library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To follow Clean Architecture principles in Android with `Room` you need to create a few mapper classes between `data <-> domain` and `domain <-> presentation` layers. An example of such a mapper could be found here: [Mapper for an Entity](https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture/blob/master/data/src/main/java/com/fernandocejas/android10/sample/data/entity/mapper/UserEntityDataMapper.java).

**Examples:**

You have your `CardEntity` in `data` layer and use mapper class to create new `Card` entity in `domain` layer. Then to pass this newly created object to `presentation` layer, you use one more mapper, that creates new `CardModel` and then you can use and manipulate it wherever you want in UI.

To create new item in Room, you do the same thing, but backwards: `CardModel` to `Card` (`presentation -> domain`) using mapper, then `Card` to `CardEntity` (`domain -> data`) using another mapper. Then just save that `CardEntity` using Room database function with `@Insert` annotation.

**NOTE:**

Even tho creating such classes make your code a bit more bulky, it follows Clean Architecture and makes every module more decoupled.

Comment: Just curious as to how you would measure that benefit? Or can you cite studies that show that everything becomes more understandable over time?

Comment: @straya Well, it has been some time since I have worked with clean architecture and Android. This answer was written almost 3 years ago... With my current experience, I would not say that it makes everything more understandable (If anyone joins the team and does not know the benefits of modular codebases, he wouldn't understand the benefit of such mappers). These type of practices make modules (domain/presentation/data/etc.) more decoupled by creating clear boundaries between them. If one module has to change, it does not effect other modules as much and sometimes at all.